# how to get sender's email address from parse.com database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have this android application which **VoteActivity.class** create custom questionnaire and send it to **voteAnswer.class** to check the radio button and answers the questionnaire. I am trying to have **voteAnswer.class** to send the answer to the sender's email address. The answers should be send to whoever created the questionnaire in the first place which can be any email. In other words, the user will be getting the answers in his/her email address. I tried fetching the email from parse.com database but it is not working. Do I need to be parse pro member? Or How how does that work? Or am I doing it wrong? 
I have been struggling with this small matter for few weeks and I would really be grateful if I received hints from experts here in stackoverflow to clear my confusion.

**My VoteAnswer.class**

```
  query.findInBackground( new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
               @Override
               public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                   if (e==null) {


                     for (int i = 0; i <objects.size(); i ++)
                      {

                          String question = objects.get(0).getString("questionare");
                          final String mO = objects.get(0).getString("optionOne");
                          final String mT = objects.get(0).getString("optionTwo");
                          final String mH = objects.get(0).getString("optionThree");

                          questionare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainQ);
                          mOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.optionO);
                          mTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.optionTW);
                          mThree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.optionTH);

                          radioVoteGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                          optionONE=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionone);
                          optionTWO=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optiontwo);
                          optionTHREE=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionthree);



                          //questionare.setText(objects.get(i).getString("questionare"));
                         // mOne.setText(objects.get(i).getString("optionOne"));
                         // mTwo.setText(objects.get(i).getString("optionTwo"));
                         // mThree.setText(objects.get(i).getString("optionThree"));
                          questionare.setText(question);
                          optionONE.setText(mO);
                          optionTWO.setText(mT);
                          optionTHREE.setText(mH);



                          //mOne.setText(mO);
                         // mTwo.setText(mT);
                         // mThree.setText(mH);


                          Log.d("questionare", "Retrieved " + objects.size()+ " questionare");

                          mButton =(Button) findViewById (R.id.Submit);
                          mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View v) {


                                  returnVoteAnswer();




                              }
                          });
                      }



                       //question = objects.toString("questionare");
                       //mO = objects.toString("optionOne");
                      // mT = objects.toString("optionTwo");
                      // mH = objects.toString("optionThree");
                       //addData();

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();

                   }
               }
           });

    }

    private String returnVoteAnswer ()
    {
        switch (radioVoteGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.optionone:
                return optionONE.getText()  .toString();
            case R.id.optiontwo:
                return optionTWO.getText().toString();
            case R.id.optionthree:
                return optionTHREE.getText().toString();
            default:
                return "";

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `User` class can only be assessed by the user itself or by master key. In your case, you can write Cloud Code function to get a user's email by using `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` method before doing a query.

Cloud Code Guide: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide

Parse is missing its Cloud Code instruction in Android Guide, so you can use following code to call a Cloud Code function.

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("objectId",objectId); //Include any param your Cloud Code needs
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("yourCloudFuction", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
      public void done(Float ratings, ParseException e) {
           if (e == null) {
                    // ratings is 4.5
           }
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and time Ralphilius. 
To get the best out of your answer, here is what I did
1. I used the cloud code you provided above to make the call to cloud code function
2. I need to write background job after to perform push operation to send the email to the senderId. 

My question is, I need to create javascript file in my android studio to write the background job according to the recommendation you provided and what I understood from it so far, correct me if I am wrong, please? 
Thanks again Raplilius

Comment: Yes, but the javascript part is not in Android Studio but on your Parse backend. You need to check **Getting Started** part in the guide in my answer to get to know how to set up and deploy your cloud functions to Parse. In my example, the callback function return a float number, you can return an email string in your cloud function.

Comment: Thank you very much Ralphilius. 
I was able to set it up and deploy the code but I am having difficult time understanding the cloud code in JS since I never used JS before. It will be helpful if you there is a lead that explains which each and every line do
Otherwise thanks my friend